# Populate select box from database value showing error on jsp page

Tags: jsp, struts2

I want to populate catList object of type arrayList in to
select box with key=catId
and value=catName

```
public class GamesAction extends ActionSupport {
 private ArrayList catList;

 public String populate() {
    GamesCategoryBusiness gcb = new GamesCategoryBusiness();
    Map data = gcb.fetchAll();//fetching games category from database
    String status = (String) data.get("status");
    if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
        setCatList((ArrayList) data.get("gameCatList"));
        return "POPULATE";
    } else {
        addActionError("Not able to fetch Game categories");
        return INPUT;
    }



 public ArrayList getCatList() {
    return catList;
}

public void setCatList(ArrayList catList) {
    this.catList = catList;
}

}
```

Another Class

```
 public class GamesCategoryAction extends ActionSupport {

private long catId;
private String catName;

public long getCatId() {
    return catId;
}

public void setCatId(long catId) {
    this.catId = catId;
}

public String getCatName() {
    return catName;
}

public void setCatName(String catName) {
    this.catName = catName;
}
```

In struts.xml

```
 <action name="gameCatAdded" class="GamesCategoryAction"
            method="addCategory">
        <result name="POPULATE">/allCategory.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/allCategory.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/addCategory.jsp</result>
        <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

In Jsp

```
 <s:select list="catList"
                     listKey="catId"
                     listValue="catName"
                     name="gamesCategoryId"
                     label="Category"
                     labelposition="top"/>
```

In jsp page it is showing follwing error
exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: tag 'select', field 'list', name 'gamesCategoryId':    The requested list key 'catList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
       org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:584)
```

Comment: The action configuration you show is for the action that doesn't have `catList`.

Comment: You show an action configuration. The action class matching that configuration doesn't have a `catList` property.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am accessing it on GamesAction which is having catList

Comment: Why show configuration/code for something unrelated, then? In any case, you'll need to provide more details. Please edit the question to include the *relevant* configuration etc. Are you actually calling the `populate` method?

Answer (score 0):

try this: `ArrayList<Catalog> catList` in the action class. Your object type is unknown, if you never declared your object type. (assuming you have a domain class called `Catalog`, which contains `catId` and `catName`)

Comment: GamesCategoryAction  contains catId and catName. I have modified the code <b> private ArrayList<GamesCategoryAction> catList; setCatList((ArrayList<GamesCategoryAction>) data.get("gameCatList"));,/>  But sowing the same exception